# Capturing local variable by value when lambda outlives local scope

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino

I'm having trouble using the value of a local variable in a lambda when the lambda outlives the local scope:

```
  void createLambda(){
    int testNum = 5;

    auto myLambda = [testNum]() mutable {
      Serial.print(testNum);
    }

    this->otherClass->handleLambda(myLambda);
  }
```

The otherClass handles the lambda by creating a new Callback instance that is uses to store the lambda:

```
class CallbackBase {
  public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
}

template<typename Func>
class Callback : public CallbackBase{
  public:
    Func funcData;

    Callback(Func func){
      funcData = func;
    };

    void execute(){
      funcData();
    }
}

class OtherClass{
  CallbackBase *callback;

  template<typename Func>
  handleLambda(Func func){

    callback = new Callback(<decltype(func)>);
  }

}
```

The lambda will be called after createLambda() has finished executing and possibly after the object that created it has been destroyed. When called after createLambda() finishes executing it always prints:

```
0
```

I understand why capturing by reference would be a problem but thought it was still possible to capture testNum by value. Is this at all possible, and if not are there any simple workarounds?

Also as a note this code is being written for the Arudino Teensy 3.1.

Comment: What's the problem? This seems fine.

Comment: Few Arduino dev tools (certainly none that I know of) *don't* use GCC.

Comment: Added edit- I thought it would do but always outputs '0'. If I execute the lambda in the createLambda() scope then it ouputs '5' like I would expect

Comment: This is C++11, does your Arduino compiler supports that syntax?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams hmmm ok, removed comment about gcc since I'm not really familiar with the compiler specs. Just wanted to make the note about Arduino since doesn't seem to support everything C++11 does. (The Uno for example doesnt support lambdas at all)

Comment: @Havenard Yes, using the Teensy 3.1 which does support lambdas in general unlike some other platforms (Uno, Mega). Not sure if this issue is related to the platform or not though.

Comment: How does otherClass->handleLambda store the object that is passed?

Comment: @MadScientist added more into to question

Comment: Your code works fine with VS2010. What happens when you replace the lambda with a hand-written function object? Aside from that - why is your lambda mutable? Why do you make a copy of func in handleLambda? Have you thought about passing func via universal reference?

Comment: By function object do you mean some type of functor? If you're referring to std::function its not available, Arduino doesn't have access to the standard library. No real reason for mutable to be there, didn't expect it to make a difference but was just trying different things (also setting capture arguments to [=] or [=, testNum]) and this tutorial seemed to imply that using mutable could make a difference : https://goparallel.sourceforge.net/c-lambda-functions-fearlessly-return-local-references/     Making the copy of func was a mistake, me mistranslating the code.

Comment: Also not very familiar with universal references (not super experienced with c++ in general), maybe I'll look more into that

Comment: Try to replace the lambda with something like `struct MyLambda { int m_value; MyLambda(int value) : m_value(value) { } void operator()() const { /* code goes here */ } };` and `MyLambda myLambda(testNum);` in createLambda